# Expect a dog: figurative meaning

Tags: figurative

What does this mean? I stumbled across it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163962.aspx):

"If the design requires a million trips to the server, expect a dog." 
(The last sentence in the paragraph titled **Efficiency**.)

Comment: General Reference. Defn 6b](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dog) *Something of inferior or low quality.* A design requiring a million trips to the server will probably lead to a poor quality piece of software (so that's what you should *expect* to end up with).

Comment: So 'expect a dog' is not an idiom: 'dog' is an unusual usage.

Comment: @Edwin: [Try it on your network, and it runs like a dog.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Try+it+on+your+network+and+it+runs+like+a+dog.%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) I'm perfectly familiar with that exact usage. To *run like a dog* (= *execute*, [of program code] *very slowly*) seems to be particularly common in the software context. I've no idea why, since dogs aren't exactly noted for being slow when it comes to running.

Comment: @FumbleFingers:  As it's obviously in a tech manual (maybe a maintainer's manual), the writer obviously expected the readers to know what he's talking about.

Comment: @ZZMike: With the exception of [James Joyce and *Finnegans Wake*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finnegans_Wake), I suppose most writers expect their readers to know what they're talking about. Both in the sense that individual words and phrases will be understood *as **part** of the normal process of reading*, and that the reader may gain understanding of higher-level meanings *as a **result** of reading*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I suspect ‘to run like a dog’ is a kind of rephrasing of another common expression: that something is (or runs) _dog-slow_, in which ‘dog’ is really just an intensifier, like ‘dead-slow’ or ‘dog-tired’. It could also possibly be from the sense of the word that refers to a slow, unmanageable horse: something that runs like such a dog runs slowly and erratically/uncontrollably.

Comment: There's a discussion [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Miscellaneous/2008_March_6#Where_does_the_Phrase_.22runs_like_a_dog_come_from.3F), which looks at both the relevant sense of _dog_, its etymology, the whole expression 'run/s like a dog', and its relative rarity. The term 'lemon' used to be quite common for a poor car, washing machine, scholar etc, at least in the UK.

Comment: @Edwin: That's an interesting Wikipedia discussion. I see one of the guys there says our usage is *a little funny because dogs don't tend to be particularly slow runners* - so obviously I'm not the only one a bit puzzled by it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, 'expect a dog' probably means 'expect slow responses'.  In relation to cars, 'dogging' started out meaning a problem with wheel alignment, which would cause a slower vehicle (via http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogging).  I've heard dogging used in context of slowness for both cars and servers (a car with a manual transmission might dog up a hill, a server with badly-written, long-running queries would dog out).  In both cases, the object does not fail at what it's trying to do, it just goes very slowly (and in the case of the server, may time out).  The use of dog to mean slow may also stem from 'dogged pursuit' i.e. someone following relentlessly, though not necessarily quickly.

Comment: Usage of "dog" as low quality seems to date from before cars existed. See etymonline's entry for [dog](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dog&allowed_in_frame=0): "Many expressions -- a dog's life (c.1600), go to the dogs (1610s), etc. -- reflect earlier hard use of the animals as hunting accessories, not pampered pets."